# What does it mean when my hero is taken out?

Tags: taken-out, danger-patrol-pocket-ed

The Pocket Edition of Danger Patrol says that a hero is "taken out" when he rolls 6 danger at once. What does that mean? Is my hero out of the game for the rest of the session, or does it mean something less drastic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused by this fact, as well. When a character was ‘taken out’ early in the session (there is only one tiny remark that suggests there might be another action scene to follow, so we were set up very all-or-nothing for a single scene in our session), we could not imagine that player being out for the rest of it and decided on the following house rule, which worked well for the purpose and created good drama later:

> When you are ‘taken out’, you can only take the Recovery action. When you take the Recovery action when taken out, you are not taken out any more, but you gain 6 threat dice.

Which means that you can either take another recovery action and be back to full strength, or you can risk life and limbs and being taken out again with a very high chance if the situation is dire. In the game we played, we saw both options taken, and our victory was narrowly achieved due to someone jumping back into the fray just after having Recovered in this manner (and immediately taken out again at the same time as the very last Threat remaining), so it worked well for the drama the game seems to be built around.

Answer (score 2):

## Until the end of the scene (probably)

Because of the short size of Danger Patrol Pocket Edition, there isn't an answer in the text for this question.

However, by analogy to the full-size Danger Patrol, you should be able to heal from being taken out in an Interlude between scenes.

> After an action scene, we play a short interlude scene. An interlude
>   is a brief bit of roleplaying or narration by a player, similar to the
>   “Previously On” moments at the beginning of the episode. They
>   should be short and punchy (no more than a minute or two). They’re
>   a chance for the players to narrate cool stuff, roleplay with each other,
>   recover from the action, and—most importantly—set up questions to
>   be answered in the next part of the game (Suspense!).